# Performing a function on rows with matching IDs

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my problem: I have a dataset like this.

---

```
  ID | Date          
1123 | 01-JUL-2015
1123 | 02-JUL-2015
1155 | 01-JUL-2015
1180 | 02-JUL-2015
1190 | 01-JUL-2015
1190 | 03-JUL-2015
```

---

The above pipe-deliminated dataset is two columns, I apologize for bad formatting.

What I need to do is find the matching IDs in the first column, and subtract the dates of the of the two matching IDs to see the difference in date. I hope to have the dataset look like the below.

---

```
  ID | Days
1123 | 1
1155 | 0
1180 | 0
1190 | 3
```

---

Does anyone know any useful functions or solutions to solve this problem? I am using Oracle SQL.

Comment: will there always be atmost 2 dates for a given id?

Comment: No, I used a DISTINCT function to filter for unique ID and Date combinations. So the only time there will be more than one is if the date value is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select id, (max(date) - min(date)) as daydiff
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My only concern is that the second select statement will find the max and min dates regardless of the ID. Or does the GROUP BY only select the min and max for specific IDs?

Comment: Nevermind, I tested this SQL code and it works just as I hoped it would. Thank you!